# All checkboxes get checked when one is checked (should be just the one checked) - inputs generated with angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am making app with angular js. It goes like this.

- User creates groups and adds group names
- User creates 'websites' and for each website he can check groups that are created in previous step

Problem is that all groups checkboxes get checked when he checks just one.

Here is the code that generates the checkboxes:

```
<p>Groups: 
<label ng-repeat='group in groups'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="newSite.groups" name="group-check" value="{{group.id}}"/> 
    {{group.name}}</label></p>
```

Here is the code that is outputed:

```
<label ng-repeat="group in groups" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="newSite.groups" name="group-check" value="0" class="ng-valid ng-dirty"> 
    first group</label>
<label ng-repeat="group in groups" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="newSite.groups" name="group-check" value="1" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> 
    second group</label>
```

Thanks!

edit: here is the plunker link http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/OVBoTDY2YmXgSy8TAbIW

Comment: You are binding the checkbox to the same model. Try creating a plunker with the minimum code to show the problem

Comment: @LiviuT. Yes, just realized that s the issue. So I guess I should remove the ng-model and update `newSite.groups` using checked/unchecked value?

Comment: its better you set up a plunker so that problem could be resolved

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal added the plunker link. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This (plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNWh8G3rUTtZVaISTr1r?p=preview) is how I would do it. The idea is to create a model to keep track of checked groups.

**JS**

```
app.controller("WebsitesCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.newSite = {};
  $scope.newGroup = {};
  $scope.checkedGroupIds = {};

  $scope.sites = [];
  var groupMap = {};
  $scope.groups = [];

  var siteIdSeq = 0;
  function createSite(newSite, groups) {
    $scope.sites.push(newSite);
    newSite.id = siteIdSeq;
    newSite.groups = groups;
    siteIdSeq++;
    return newSite;
  }

  var groupIdSeq = 0;
  function createGroup(newGroup) {
    $scope.groups.push(newGroup);
    newGroup.id = groupIdSeq;
    groupMap[newGroup.id] = newGroup;
    groupIdSeq++;
    return newGroup;
  }

  $scope.submitSite = function() { 
    var groups = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.checkedGroupIds, function(checked, id) {
      if(checked) {
        groups.push(groupMap[id]);
      }
    });

    createSite($scope.newSite, groups);
    $scope.newSite = {};
    $scope.checkedGroupIds = {};
  };

  $scope.submitGroup = function() {
    createGroup($scope.newGroup);
    $scope.newGroup = {};
  };

  //test data
  $scope.newSite.url = 'http://www.my-site.com';
  var all = createGroup({name:'All'});
  var home = createGroup({name:'Home'});
  var fav = createGroup({name:'Fav'});

  createSite({url:'http://www.stackoverflow.com'}, [all, fav]);
  createSite({url:'http://www.google.com'}, [fav]);
  createSite({url:'http://www.plnkr.co'}, [home]);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="website-form">
  Sites:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="site in sites">{{site}}</li>
  </ul>

  <form ng-submit="submitSite()">
    <label>Site url: <input type="url" ng-model="newSite.url" /></label>
    <p>Groups: 
      <label ng-repeat='group in groups'>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="group-check" value="{{group.name}}" id="{{group.id}}" 
          ng-model="checkedGroupIds[group.id]" /> 
      {{group.name}}
      </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" id="submitWebsite" value="Save Changes" ng-disabled="!newSite.url" />
  </form><!-- end submitSite() -->
</div>

<div id="group-form">
  <form ng-submit="submitGroup()">
    <label>Name of the group: <input ng-model="newGroup.name" /></label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitGroup" value="Save Changes"
      ng-disabled="!newGroup.name"/>
    </form><!-- end submitGroup() -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'll modify it a bit but this is essentially what I needed!