# Get selected data from checkbox in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, checkbox

I have a form with multiple checkboxes where I display checkbox data from a JSON file using ng-repeat. Now, when I submit the form, I want to get the checked data from the checkboxes. How can I access checked data after the form is submitted? 
I did some research and now I can display the checked data on page itself using `ng-model="s.checked"` but how can I access the checked data at controller's end.

See this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekGNwPvCpGpkSyaOh74t?p=preview) for details

Comment: possible duplicate of [All checkboxes get checked when one is checked (should be just the one checked) - inputs generated with angular js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487951/all-checkboxes-get-checked-when-one-is-checked-should-be-just-the-one-checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of `$scope.List` hasn't changed when you submit, it's still an array of objects. You could do something like

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var checkedItems = $scope.List.filter(function(item){
        return item.checked;
    });
    console.log(checkedItems);
};
```

The values of the `List` items have changed.

(Also, it's generally a good idea to use [ngSubmit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit))

Comment: Maybe the only thing to add there is that `Array.prototype.filter` is [not supported](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.filter) on IE8 (and IE7).

Answer (score 0):

You have array of objects:

```
$scope.list = [
{"ID":5000,"Name":"ABC",checked:true},
{"ID":5001,"Name":"DEF",checked:false},
{"ID":5002,"Name":"XYZ",checked:false}];
```

so you can access the values of checked properties like this:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var val1 = $scope.list[0].checked;
    var val2 = $scope.list[1].checked;
    var val3 = $scope.list[2].checked;
}
```

Or with the use of `forEach` statement:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.list, function (listValue) {
       var val = listValue.checked;
    });
}
```